# Control Flow. Promise Logic. How to deviate without the deviation eloping with the control flow, leaving behind basically just an IOU (Promise)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm having trouble understanding control flow with asynchronous programming in JS. I come from classic OOP background. eg. C++. Your program starts in the "main" -- top level -- function and it calls other functions to do stuff, but everything always comes back to that main function and it retains overall control.  And each sub-function retains control of what they're doing even when they call sub functions.  Ultimately the program ends when that main function ends. (That said, that's about as much as I remember of my C++ days so answers with C++ analogies might not be helpful lol).

This makes control flow relatively easy. But I get how that's not designed to handle event driven programming as needed on something like a web server. While Javascript (let's talk node for now, not browser) handles event-driven web servers with callbacks and promises, with relative ease... apparently.

I think I've finally got my head around the idea that with event-driven programming the entry point of the app might do little more than set up a bunch of listeners and then get out of the way (effectively end itself). The listeners pick up all the action and respond.

But sometimes stuff still has to be synchronous, and this is where I keep getting unstuck.

With callbacks, promises, or async/await, we can effectively build synchronous chains of events.  eg with Promises:

```
doSomething()
.then(result => doSomethingElse(result))
.then(newResult => doThirdThing(newResult))
.then(finalResult => {
    console.log(`Got the final result: ${finalResult}`);
})
.catch(failureCallback);
});
```

Great.  I've got a series of tasks I can do in order -- kinda like more traditional synchronous programming.

My question is: sometimes you need to deviate from the chain. Ask some questions and act differently depending on the answers. Perhaps conditionally there's some other function you need to call to get something else you need along the way. You can't continue without it. But what if it's an async function and all it's going to give me back is a promise? How do I get the actual result without the control flow running off and eloping with that function and never coming back?

Example:

I want to call an API in a database, get a record, do something with the data in that record, then write something back to the database. I can't do any of those steps without completing the previous step first. Let's assume there aren't any sync functions that can handle this API. No problem. A Promise chain (like the above) seems like a good solution.

But... Let's say when I call the database the first time, the authorization token I picked up earlier for it has expired and I have to get a new one. I don't know that until I make that first call. I don't want to get (or even test for the need for) a new auth token every time.  I just want to be able to respond when a call fails because I need one.

Ok... In synchronous pseudo-code that might look something like this:

```
let Token = X
Step 1: Call the database(Token).  Wait for the response.
Step 2: If response says need new token, then:
    Token = syncFunctionThatGetsAndReturnsNewToken(). 
        // here the program waits till that function is done and I've got my token.
    Repeat Step 1
End if
Step 3: Do the rest of what I need to do.
```

But now we need to do it in Javascript/node with only async functions, so we can use a promise (or callback) chain?

```
let Token = X
CallDatabase(Token)
.then(check if response says we need new token, and if so, get one)
.then(...
```

Wait a sec.  That "if so, get one" is the part that's screwing me. All this asynchronicity in JS/node isn't going to wait around for that. That function is just going to "promise" me a new token sometime in the future. It's an IOU. Great. Can't call the database with an IOU. Well ok, I'd be happy to wait, but node and JS won't let me, because that's blocking.

That's it in a (well, ok, rather large) nutshell. What am I missing? How do I do something like the above with callbacks or Promises?

I'm sure there's a stupid "duh" moment in my near future here, thanks to one or more of you wonderful people.  I look forward to it.   Thanks in advance!

Comment: If _Step 2_ tells you that you need a new token, then you have to leave that "chain" of actions to first get a new token and then start again from _Step 1_. That's the same for the async way. Either `CallDatabase()` will raise an exception or you have to in the next `.then()` to stop the execution and start over again with a new token. Or check the token before you use it: `const token = await GetToken(); const data = await CallDatabase(); ...`

Comment: @Andreas. Thanks. Good points. Though couple of things: 1. In this case, checking the token before I use it will add an extra overhead I'm not keen on. So, trying to avoid that. 2. I'm a bit lost as to how "stop the execution and start over again with a new token" works. What's controlling the "start over again" part? Or... once I've sent the promise chain on its merry way, how does what called it know what happened, in order to start over if it has to stop (without just shoehorning this into sync-think per my response to Eduard below)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do with the `.then` call is to attach a function which will run when the Promise resolves in a future *task*. The processing of that function is itself synchronous, and can use all the control flows you'd want:

```
 getResponse()
.then(response => {
   if(response.needsToken) 
      return getNewToken().then(getResponse);
})
.then(() => /* either runs if token is not expired or token was renewed */)
```

If the token is expired, instead of directly scheduling the Promise returned by `.then`, a new asynchronous action gets started to retrieve a new token. If that asynchronous action is done, in a new task it'll resolve the Promise it returns, and as that Promise was returned from the `.then` callback, this will also then resolve the outer Promise and the Promise chain continues.

Note that these Promise chains can get complicated very quick, and with `async function`s this can be written more elegantly (though under the hood it is about the same):

```
 do {
   response = await getResponse();
   if(response.needsToken)
      await renewToken();
 } while(response.needsToken)
```

Comment: Hey @Jonas. Great stuff. Thanks. Couple of questions…
1. Agreed async/await can solve a lot of this. Doing some of that now, but finding myself “cheating” just sticking await in front of everything to work it like C etc. instead of properly "getting" async-think. Want to get it right with Promises so I’m sure I “get” it.
2. “either runs if token…” (or possibly the previous then) -- it's step 1 that needs to (re-)run there. I have to rewrite step 1’s code there or is there some way to loop back to step 1? Getting lost there. Hmm… recursive function call? What's best practice here?

Comment: Yes, exactly, a "pseudorecursive function call" as I'd like to call it (unlike real recursion it'll not fill up the stack, cause each call will happen in it's own task / stack and the synchronous callstack unwinds inbetween). Something like `const recurse = () => Promise.resolve().then(recurse);`

Comment: I've added a concrete example to the answer.

Comment: Ah. Thanks so much @Jonas. That's clearer for sure. I think there's one of those "duh" moments: Functionalize (I'm sure that's not a word lol) my step 1. Now I'm wondering why that didn't already occur to me... ••• This implies part of my perhaps deficient thinking is: relying perhaps too much on control flow statements like loops, whereas compartmentalizing/abstracting more code into functions would make this promise stuff a lot easier. Does that sound like a reasonable statement?

Comment: Kind of. Functions (non async ones) always run to completion, that is they finish within a task. In the async world you always have at least two tasks, one that kicks of the async process and the other one that runs when it finishes. Thus you need at least two functions. For a loop with n iterations you'll need n functions, or rather a recursive call.

Comment: That's a good way to put it. Thanks again! My prior implementation of the example in my question was with a for loop from 0 to 1 -- the second iteration gets canceled if the first one works. Kinda conceptually the same? But I knew there had to be a better way, just couldn't grasp it. This makes some sense, though I’d like to clarify a couple more things if possible. Would you be willing to chat some more (specifically on this)? I’ve done that here before but can’t remember, or seem to figure out, how to initiate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231761/discussion-between-davidt-and-jonas-wilms).

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, I would recommend against using then and catch method to listen to Promise result. They tend to create a too nested code which is hard to read and maintain.

I worked a prototype for your case which makes use of async/await. It also features a mechanism to keep track of attempts we are making to authenticate to database. If we reach max attempts, it would be viable to send an emergency alert to administrator etc for notification purposes. This avoid the endless loop of trying to authenticate and instead helps you to take proper actions.

```
'use strict'

var token;

async function getBooks() {
    // In case you are not using an ORM(Sequelize, TypeORM), I would suggest to use
    // at least a query builder like Knex
    const query = generateQuery(options);
    const books = executeQuery(query)
}

async function executeQuery(query) {
    let attempts = 0;
    let authError = true;

    if (!token) {
        await getDbAuthToken();
    }

    while (attemps < maxAttemps) {
        try {
            attempts++;
            // call database
            // return result
        }
        catch(err) {
            // token expired
            if (err.code == 401) {
                await getDbAuthToken();
            }
            else {
                authError = false;
            }
        }
    }

    throw new Error('Crital error! After several attempts, authentication to db failed. Take immediate steps to fix this')
}

// This can be sync or async depending on the flow 
// how the auth token is retrieved
async function getDbAuthToken() {

}
```

Comment: Hey @Eduard. Thanks for this. Some good points and a nice workup. Agreed, async/await does solve some of the problems, but I really want to understand this with Promises or even callbacks. I'm currently finding myself working around my async challenges by just building everything synchronously by making nearly every function async, and prefixing every line that lets me, with await - so just hacking JS to behave like C, etc.  While that works, I suspect I'm kinda missing the point. I think I need to better understand async-think. That said, great point with the tracking and notifying. Thanks!